# How to map an object

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem. I want to map a response object to an array. Basically, mapping is used if the response is an array too but in this case the response from server is an object. How do I map that?

getuser.js

```
this.state = {
          post : '',
          post2 : [],
          formData : {
            username : '',
            clientId : ''
          }

getPostAPI = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const { post } = this.state
        const { username } = this.state.formData

        axios.post(`http://10.40.22.21:8062/users/get`, { username } ,
          {
            headers:
              {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
                "AUTHENTICATION-KEY" : token, 
              }
          })
        .then((res)=>{
            let response = res;
            if(response){  

                this.setState ({
                  post : response.data.response
                })  

                console.log(response.data.response)

              }

        },this)
        .catch( (error) => {        
              alert('Username Tidak di Temukan',error)
            }
        )
  }
```

myForm in GETuser.js

```
{
                  Object.values(post).map((h,i) => (

                  <tr key = {i} >
                  <th scope="row">
                    <Media className="align-items-center">
                      <Media>
                        <span className="badge-dot mr-4">
                          {h.username}
                        </span>
                      </Media>
                    </Media>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <Media className="align-items-center">
                      <Media>
                        <span className="badge-dot mr-4">
                          {h.firstName}
                        </span>
                      </Media>
                    </Media>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <Media className="align-items-center">
                      <Media>
                        <span className="badge-dot mr-4">
                          {h.password}
                        </span>
                      </Media>
                    </Media>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="row">
                    <Media className="align-items-center">

                      <Media>
                        <button  className="btn btn-danger" onClick= {() => this.handleRemove(post.clientId)}><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>                        

                      </Media>
                    </Media>
                  </th>


                </tr>
                ))
```

response from server

```
{
  "responseCode":"00",
   "message":"Process successful. ",
   "localMessage":"Proses Berhasil.",
    "response" : {"username":"admin","firstName":"admin","middleName":"is","lastName":"admin","password":"fZE+K9bKT29FAEOaJbfFw==","effectiveDate":"25-01-2019 07:00:00","expiredDate":"25-01-2021 07:00:00","phone":"082234051157","email":"asdsad@gmail.com"}}
```

i expect cant post.map so i can use the acction delete or update thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, with your case. You just do like this (ES6):

```
const result = [ response.data.response ]
this.setState ({
   post : result
})
```

Now, this.state.post will be:

```
[
    {
        "username": "admin",
        "firstName": "admin",
        "middleName": "is",
        "lastName": "admin",
        "password": "fZE+K9bKasdsaASDJbfFw==",
        "effectiveDate": "25-01-2019 07:00:00",
        "expiredDate": "25-01-2021 07:00:00",
        "phone": "082233051157",
        "email": "asdasdasn@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: thankyouuuu broo. you helped me alot . i set post : [response.data.response]. and use Object.values(post).map thankkyouu

Comment: Yes. now, you can use `this.state.post.map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert object to an array, you have the following options:

1) **`Object.values(post.response)`** will give you the values of the object as an array.

2) **`Object.keys(post.response)`** will give you keys of the object as an array.

3) **`Object.entries(post.response)`** will give you an array where each element is an array consisting of the key and value.

So instead you can do this:

```
Object.keys(response).map( heading =>
<tr>
 <th scope="row">
  <Media className="align-items-center">
   <Media>
    <span className="badge-dot mr-4">
     {heading}
    </span>
   </Media>
  </Media>
 </th>
<td scope="row">
  <Media className="align-items-center">
   <Media>
    <span className="badge-dot mr-4">
     {response[heading]}
    </span>
   </Media>
  </Media>
 </td>
```

This way you can dynamically define the columns based on the object properties and output the respective values.

Comment: i already try it, but the looping output. when the data in response 9, so the username will return 9x

Comment: like this ```Object.values(post).map(post => (```

Comment: what is the desired output that you want to see in the `post` inside of state?

Comment: output to horizontal.

Comment: so i create into table

Comment: I am not sure I understand - could you edit the original question so that it shows the desired output as a data structure?

Comment: i want get data from response to an array so i want to make the reponse to post [] , and mapping that.

Comment: and as we know the response is an object not an array.

Comment: The post should not be an array - an array is a collection of items, post is something that has properties so it is an object. I think it would really help if you edited your post and displayed the exact data structure that you want to see:

Comment: bro my simple question hwo to mapping the response into table if the response like above . i will edit the post

Comment: its the response from server . not own create.

Comment: ```
this.state = {
   post : [//what do you want to see here?]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting response you can store response in post array using setstate.

```
this.setState({post2:response})
```

Comment: -.-, bro its an object. i want to get data from response.data.response to array in variable post : []. so i can mapping that to the table

Comment: Post is an array so when You set response in post.it is store in array form.